# codeigniter helloworld app not running for some reason

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to follow a tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-basics--net-2634) which is just a simple helloworld that pulls data from a database.

I'm using CI 3.0.6.

I have never used codeigniter before, but I wanted to try a framework.

Anyways, I think I followed the tutorial correctly (I do think the tutorial uses a slightly older version of codeigniter as some of the paths are a bit different) but I cannot get this to work, it gives me the error `The page you requested was not found.`

I have a few questions on this.

The tutorial tells me to use a model, but what *is* a model?

How can I get this working? If I can get this working properly I have no doubt I can use it as a learning experience to expand my project.

My code:
helloworld.php (Controller @ BASEDIR/application/controllers)_:

```
<?php
    class Helloworld extends Controller{
        function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('helloworld_model');

            $data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model-><span class="sql">getData</span>();
            $data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";

            $this->load->view('helloworld_view',$data);
        }
    }
?>
```

helloworld_model.php (Model @ BASEDIR/application/models):

```
<?php
class Helloworld_model extends Model {

    function Helloworld_model()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::Model();
    }

    function getData()
        {
            //Query the data table for every record and row
            $query = $this->db->get('data');

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                //show_error('Database is empty!');
            }else{
                return $query->result();
            }
        }

}
?>
```

helloworld_view (view @ BASEDIR/application/views):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$page_title?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php foreach($result as $row):?>
        <h3><?=$row->title?></h3>
        <p><?=$row->text?></p>
        <br />
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </body>
</html>
```

my db info:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'private',
    'username' => 'private',
    'password' => 'private',
    'database' => 'database',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysql';
    'dbprefix' => 'va',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

& my autoload:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

I'm trying to access the page by going to http://myurl.com/dev/index.php/helloworld/

/dev/ is my installation directory.

Again, I've never used a framework before so this question is probably really simple to fix.

Comment: which ci version you are using ?

Comment: also your db credentials are wrong

Comment: @SoravGarg 3.0.6 - what do you mean they are wrong?

Comment: in hostname your inserted only colon

Comment: @SoravGarg No, its the right info in my code, I just cleared it out on Stack.

Comment: in your project controller class name and file name are same ?

Comment: what error you are facing ?

Comment: @SoravGarg Did you read the post?

Comment: You missed almost all propositions CodeIgniter docs demand. **1.)** Controller file name should be ucfirst() named. **2.)** `class Helloworld extends Controller{` should be `class Helloworld extends CI_Controller{`. **3.)** Don't close PHP tag at the end of file. This is what I see at first look. Edit: now I am seeing you are following tutorial for CodeIgniter <=1.7.2 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you followed that tutorial completely then you need to access that page without index.php in url.

Also use PHP5 constructors so change:

```
function Helloworld_model()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::Model();
}
```

To:

```
function __construct()
{
    // Call the Model constructor
    parent::__construct();
}
```

This also makes no sense:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    //show_error('Database is empty!');
}
else
{
    return $query->result();
}
```

The code inside if/else should be switched. If number of rows returned is greater than 0 then return result else show error that database is empty.

And last thing in controller:

```
$data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model-><span class="sql">getData</span>();
```

Store only database result to data variable, pass it to view and wrap whatever elements of the data in the view.

```
$data['result'] = $this->helloworld_model->getData();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read a documentation controller
[enter link description here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html)

you can see that in application/controller/Name.php the name of the controller needs to be capitalize, inside the class you need to have (remember extends CI_Controller)

```
<?php
class Controller_name extends CI_Controller {

        public function view($page = 'home')
        {
        }
}
```

the call to the model is ok `$this->load->model('helloworld_model');`m but remember that in applicatoin/models/Model_name.php needs to be capitalized too, and insede you need to have (remember extends CI_Model)

```
<?php 
class Blog_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                // Call the CI_Model constructor
                parent::__construct();
        }
```

Yes, you needs to autoload database, but in you database config (application/config/database.php) change dbdriver to **mysqli**